# Take nth column in a text file

Tags: linux, bash

I have a text file:

```
1 Q0 1657 1 19.6117 Exp
1 Q0 1410 2 18.8302 Exp
2 Q0 3078 1 18.6695 Exp
2 Q0 2434 2 14.0508 Exp
2 Q0 3129 3 13.5495 Exp
```

I want to take the 2nd and 4th word of every line like this:

```
1657 19.6117
1410 18.8302
3078 18.6695
2434 14.0508
3129 13.5495
```

I'm using this code:

```
 nol=$(cat "/path/of/my/text" | wc -l)
 x=1
 while  [ $x -le "$nol" ]
 do
     line=($(sed -n "$x"p /path/of/my/text)
     echo ""${line[1]}" "${line[3]}""  >> out.txt
     x=$(( $x + 1 ))
 done
```

It works, but it is very complicated and takes a long time to process long text files.

Is there a simpler way to do this?

Comment: 2nd word of every row called 2nd column simply!

Answer (score 155, accepted):

iirc :

```
cat filename.txt | awk '{ print $2 $4 }'
```

or, as mentioned in the comments :

```
awk '{ print $2 $4 }' filename.txt
```

Comment: UUOC!!! `awk '{print $2,$4}' filename.txt` is better (no pipe, just one program called)

Comment: @blue I often use `cat` in my bash scripts instead of specifying a filename, because the overhead is minimal and because the syntax `cat ... | ... > ...` shows really nicely what the input is and where the output goes. You're right though, it's not actually needed here.

Comment: @TomvanderWoerdt: I sometimes write `< input   awk '{ print $2 $4 }'  > output` for that purpose.

Comment: Also, with pipes or i/o redirection you make sure that the program being executed do not modify your files.

Answer (score 78):

You can use the `cut` command:

```
cut -d' ' -f3,5 < datafile.txt
```

prints

```
1657 19.6117
1410 18.8302
3078 18.6695
2434 14.0508
3129 13.5495
```

the

- `-d' '` - mean, use `space` as a delimiter
- `-f3,5` - take and print 3rd and 5th column

The `cut` is *much faster* for large files as a pure shell solution. If your file is delimited with multiple whitespaces, you can remove them first, like:

```
sed 's/[\t ][\t ]*/ /g' < datafile.txt | cut -d' ' -f3,5
```

where the (gnu) sed will replace any `tab` or `space` characters with a single `space`.

For a variant - here is a perl solution too:

```
perl -lanE 'say "$F[2] $F[4]"' < datafile.txt
```

Comment: Works well...if you're guaranteed that number of spaces on each line, exactly... :)

Answer (score 27):

For the sake of completeness:

```
while read -r _ _ one _ two _; do
    echo "$one $two"
done < file.txt
```

Instead of `_` an arbitrary variable (such as `junk`) can be used as well. The point is just to extract the columns.

Demo:

```
$ while read -r _ _ one _ two _; do echo "$one $two"; done < /tmp/file.txt
1657 19.6117
1410 18.8302
3078 18.6695
2434 14.0508
3129 13.5495
```

Comment: Nice, readable, and no perls/awks/others needed, all in one shell by builtins.

Comment: Use `read -r` to remove the escaping quality of `\\`.

Comment: Added, thanks @TomHale

Answer (score 9):

One more simple variant -

```
$ while read line
  do
      set $line          # assigns words in line to positional parameters
      echo "$3 $5"
  done < file
```

Comment: Use `read -r` to remove the escaping quality of `\\`.

Answer (score 4):

If your file contains *n* lines, then your script has to read the file *n* times; so if you double the length of the file, you quadruple the amount of work your script does — and almost all of that work is simply thrown away, since all you want to do is loop over the lines in order.

Instead, the best way to loop over the lines of a file is to use a `while` loop, with the condition-command being the `read` builtin:

```
while IFS= read -r line ; do
    # $line is a single line of the file, as a single string
    : ... commands that use $line ...
done < input_file.txt
```

In your case, since you want to split the line into an array, and the `read` builtin actually has special support for populating an array variable, which is what you want, you can write:

```
while read -r -a line ; do
    echo ""${line[1]}" "${line[3]}"" >> out.txt
done < /path/of/my/text
```

or better yet:

```
while read -r -a line ; do
    echo "${line[1]} ${line[3]}"
done < /path/of/my/text > out.txt
```

However, for what you're doing you can just use the `cut` utility:

```
cut -d' ' -f2,4 < /path/of/my/text > out.txt
```

(or `awk`, as Tom van der Woerdt suggests, or `perl`, or even `sed`).

Comment: would prefer `read` over `cut` because it's robust against multiple spaces between the fields and you don't need array magic: `while read word1 word2 word3 word4 rest; do doSomethingWith $word2 $word4; done`

Answer (score 3):

If you are using structured data, this has the added benefit of not invoking an extra shell process to run `tr` and/or `cut` or something. ...

(Of course, you will want to guard against bad inputs with conditionals and sane alternatives.)

```
...
while read line ; 
do 
    lineCols=( $line ) ;
    echo "${lineCols[0]}"
    echo "${lineCols[1]}"
done < $myFQFileToRead ; 
...
```