# What defines a "column" in bash? In awk?

Tags: bash, awk, cat

I was viewing this question: [Bash - Take nth column in a text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17137269/bash-take-nth-column-in-a-text-file)

I want to make a function that writes to a textfile that I can then parse using the method above. So, for example, I want my function to write 'dates' in the first column, 'ID's in the second column, and 'addresses' in the third column. Then once I have this, a user could, for example, see if a certain ID is present in the file by querying for the second column, then looking at each item there. The user could do this using the method discussed in the question above.

What defines a column? Is it just a space delimiter? Is it a tab?

If I want to output this information as stated above, what would the method where I write to the file look like? So far I have:

```
cat "$DATE $ID $ADDRESS \n" > myfile.data
```

Comment: awk is not bash, and awk's idea of what is or isn't a column has nothing whatsoever to do with bash. awk would still have that same idea of what a column is if you called it from a C program, or a Python program, or any other non-shell thing.

Comment: Thus, this question should ask about bash, or it should awk about awk, but it should not conflate the two topics by seeming to ask about both.

Comment: BTW, `cat "$DATE $ID $ADDRESS \n"` tries to read a **file** named by the expansion of `$DATE $ID $ADDRESS \n`; surely, that's not what you want.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy my apologies. I was not aware of the distinction. What is protocol now that I realize the mistake? Should I edit the question? It seems difficult since apparently I had two distinct questions and both were answered already.

Comment: (also, you shouldn't use all-caps variable names in shell scripts; shell variables share a namespace with environment variables, and the guidelines for environment variable names are given in the fourth paragraph of http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap08.html)

Comment: It is indeed tricky in that case. I'd at least suggest amending the question to make the two subquestions distinct, so as to not unnecessarily confuse other folks trying to learn from it.

Comment: Alternately, since my answer is the only one talking about bash, you could make the question explicitly about awk, and I'll delete it.

Comment: I'll edit the question to ask about how to define a column with `awk` and how bash itself defines a column. If that's good enough for you to keep your answer.

Comment: I'd suggest BashFAQ #1 at http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001 if you want non-awk-based best practices for reading a file with columns from bash, btw.

Comment: To be clear on terminology: there ARE NO COLUMNS in bash, nor in awk. In both bash and awk there are FIELDS and that is why bash has the Input Field Separator (`IFS`) variable and awk has the input (small-i as not part of the variable name this time) Field Separator (`FS`) and Output FIeld Separator (`OFS`). btw do not use the accepted answer in the question you referenced as both the bash and shell solutions in it are just plain wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In **bash**, as opposed to awk, columns are separated by characters in `IFS`.

That is to say, if you set:

```
IFS=$'\t'
```

...then columns, as understood by bash builtins such as `read first second rest`, will be separated by tabs. On the output side, `printf '%s\n' "${array[*]}"` will print the items in the array `array` separated by the first character of `IFS`.

The default value of `IFS` is equivalent to `$' \t\n'` -- that is, the space, the tab, and the newline character.

---

To write a file with a delimiter of your choice, and (presumably) more than one row (replace the `while read` with however you're actually getting your data, or only use the inside of the loop if you're only writing one line):

```
while read -r date id address; do
  printf '%s\t' "$date" "$id" "$address" >&3; printf '\n' >&3
done 3>filename
```

...or, if you don't want the trailing tab left by the above:

```
IFS=$'\t' # use a tab as the field separator for output
while IFS=$' \t\n' read -r date id address; do
  entry=( "$date" "$id" "$address" )
  printf '%s\n' "${entry[*]}" >&3
done 3>filename
```

Putting `3>filename` on the outside of the loop is **much** more efficient than `>>filename` on each line, which re-opens the output file once per line written.

Answer (score 2):

If you're going to use `awk`, the columns are separated by the *field separator*. See `FS` in `man awk` for details.

Most tools support some ways of changing the column separator:

```
cut -f
sort -t
```

`bash` itself uses the `IFS` variable (Internal Field Separator) for word splitting.

`cat` awaits file as an argument. To output a string, use `echo` instead.

Answer (score 1):

If we are talking about `awk` then the space character is the default column separator.

Its easy to change what is used as the "Field Separator" (FS) when `awk` is parsing a file: `awk '{FS=",";print $2}'`. Will use comma as the separator (note: does not respect quotes and stuff like a csv parser).

To write to the file I would use `echo` and the double carrot `>>`.

`>>` appends whereas `>` rewrites the file.
`echo -e` will let echo recognize `\n` and similar special chars

So the command would be

```
echo -e "$DATE $ID $ADDRESS \n" >> myfile.data
```

Comment: I'd argue that `echo -e` is bad advice here -- what if the values contain backslash literals? Also, any implementation of `echo` supporting `-e` violates the POSIX spec given at http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/utilities/echo.html (not **extends** it, **violates** it; a POSIX-compliant `echo` given `-e` on its command line must print `-e` on its output).

Comment: ...if `POSIXLY_CORRECT=1` is set in the environment, even GNU echo will behave thus.

Comment: Also, `echo` already puts a newline after each line of output; are you sure two newlines (one explicit, one implicit) is desired behavior?

Comment: (Also, using `>>` on the individual command writing a single line opens the file, writes that one line, and closes the file; unless one line is all you're going to write, it's wildly inefficient).