# Shell script to get dynamic values of fields

Tags: shell

I have a output file with content:

```
S0     S1     E      O      P     YGC     YGCT    FGC    FGCT     GCT    LGCC                 GCC
29.43   0.00  12.19  37.06  59.67  23968   42.189 375851 1785.339 1827.528 CMS Final Remark     No GC
```

I need to extract only the last two fields..LGCC and GCC.
But the values are generated dynamically. so can not extact them by delimeter space. How can I get this two values? what ever be the values be?

the output should be:

```
LGCC                 GCC
CMS Final Remark     No GC
```

Please suggest

Comment: what is your exact expected output based on provided input?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bash - Take nth column in a text file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17137269/bash-take-nth-column-in-a-text-file)

Answer (score 0):

maybe this can help you

```
awk '{for(i=11;i<=NF;i++){printf "%s ", $i}; printf "\n"}' yourFile
```

example;

```
user@host:/tmp$ awk '{for(i=11;i<=NF;i++){printf "%s ", $i}; printf "\n"}' t1
LGCC GCC 
CMS Final Remark No GC
```

Answer (score 0):

This is taking reference about number of columns from header row. Rest it will remove first few columns apart from last two. sed is used to remove leading while spaces caused by removing few columns.

```
awk 'NR==1{x=NF-1;} NR!=1{for(i=1;i<(x);i++) $i="" } NR!=1{print $0}' infile|sed "s/^[ \t]*//"
CMS Final Remark No GC
```