# Get the third element of a line into a file with script shell

Tags: shell

I'm doing a script shell and I want to read data inside a file. In the file, I have something like :

> /path/to/file1 something 0
>
> /path/to/file2 something2 1
>
> /path/to/file3 something3 2

What I want is to get the third element of the line but I don't know how to do it.
In my code, I have:

```
while read line;
do
    //must echo the third element of the line
done < file | sort -n -k 2 -t " "
```

I already tried with `awk` but it didn't work.

How should I do please ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bash - Take nth column in a text file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17137269/bash-take-nth-column-in-a-text-file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try something like this;

```
while read line;
do
path=$(echo $line | awk '{print  $1}')
secondColumn=$(echo $line | awk '{print  $2}')
thirdColumn=$(echo $line | awk '{print  $3}')

echo $path
echo $secondColumn
echo $thirdColumn

done < test
```

Answer (score 1):

This works if fields are separated by space:

```
$ echo 'foo bar baz' | cut --delimiter=' ' --fields=3
baz
```

This works for most whitespace separators:

```
$ echo 'foo bar baz' | awk '{print $3}'
baz
```

Comment: The both does the same, but can you explain me why I get "1 2" when I do a `path=$( cut --delimiter=' ' --fields=3 ); echo $path` ? I don't understand why I get only two of the three data ?

Comment: You didn't paste the whole command, because that would never get to the `echo` part…

Comment: Ok, I changed to `echo $line | cut --delimiter=' ' --fields=3` but I have a "Permission denied"

Comment: Are you sure you didn't do `$(echo […])`? Because that will try to *execute* the result. Please ask another question if you have problems related to other commands.

Comment: No, no, just `echo $()`

Comment: That command does not make sense - it does not contain what you wrote above, and does nothing useful. Please post the *full* command as a separate question if you think it's exhibiting non-obvious behaviour.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127111/discussion-between-erlaunis-and-l0b0).